# Promise Fulfilled But Still Pending

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, request-promise

I'm writing a function that sends a POST request to my backend API and returns the response as data. I need to use a POST request because I need to send information to the backend. I'm using async/await syntax.

When I console log the data inside the function definition, it clearly shows a resolved promise because the data is logged as an array.

```
(491) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

However, when I actually call the function, it returns a promise that is fulfilled, with the results (!!), but still pending.

```
Promise {<pending>}
    [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: Array(491)
```

I also can't use "await" outside of the function definition so that doesn't work. I've also tried using .then() after the function call but it doesn't work either.

My frontend is also throwing this error:

```
TypeError: data.slice is not a function
```

When I console.log the type of the data variable, I get:

```
object
```

Here's my code. Please help!

````
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
// import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate"
import Record from "../components/Record"
import FieldName from "../components/FieldName"

const Index = (props) => {
    // let data = useLoaderData()

    const fetchRecords = async (currentPage) => {
        const response = await fetch("https://medwallet-backend.onrender.com/data", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                currentPage: currentPage
            })
        })

        const data = await response.json()
        return await data
    }

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

    const data = fetchRecords(currentPage).then((data) => {return data})

    const recordsPerPage = 10
    const lastIndex = currentPage * recordsPerPage
    const firstIndex = lastIndex - recordsPerPage
    const records = data.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex)
    const numPages = Math.ceil(data.length / recordsPerPage)

    const handlePageClick = (e) => {
        const page_number = e.selected + 1
        setCurrentPage(page_number)
    }
 
    return <div className="index-container">
            <div className="field-names">
                {fieldNames.map((fieldName) => 
                    <FieldName fieldName={fieldName} key={fieldName} />
                )}
            </div>

            <div className="records">
                {records.map((record) => 
                    <Record record={record} key={record.record_id}/>
                 )}
            </div>

            <ReactPaginate
                previousLabel={"Prev"}
                nextLabel={"Next"}
                breakLabel={"..."}
                pageCount={numPages}
                marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                pageRangeDisplayed={3}
                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                containerClassName={"pagination justify-content-center"}
                pageClassName={"page-item"}
                pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                previousClassName={"page-item"}
                previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                nextClassName={"page-item"}
                nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                breakClassName={"page-item"}
                breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                activeClassName={"active"}
            />

    </div>
}

export default Index```
````

Comment: This seems more likely to just be the console confusing you, it might have been pending on the original print but fullfilled by the time you expanded the statement? I just tested it with `new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))` and yes, it looks exactly like that. The initial print says <pending>, but if I expand it after 2 seconds it says fullfilled while still "pending". It's not though, the print just doesn't update.

Comment: @somethinghere I don't believe so, because my frontend is throwing the following error: data.slice is not a function. So data should be an array, but when I console.log the type of the data variable, it says "object", which I assume is a promise object.

Comment: Yes, unless you `await` the results you will not get the array. Your `const data` is indeed _just a promise_, the array only exists inside your `.then`, or after `await`. Returning in the then does not magically change the thing assigned to `data`. All things you want to do _after_ the promise resolves either need to go inside your `.then`, or after an `await`.

Comment: @somethinghere I see, how do I use the await method? I don't wait to put all the logic below the function inside it because I think I would confuse myself.

Comment: Either make your entire `Index` function `async` so you can use `await`, or move the code for handling the loaded data into the `.then`. If you can't do either, you will just need to update your output later. I'm presuming this is some kind of react stuff, so that's why it has those hooks to update data later when you have it, and just use an empty array before that. Code sadly doesn't care about your confusion :) This is something we all have to deal with, and it's part of being a developer.

Comment: Yep I'm using React! Yes I wish code cared :') Okay, I made my Index function async and then changed the function call line to the following:
```
const data = await fetchRecords(currentPage)
```
But now I'm getting this error:
```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: You can't just set a variable equal to a promise, unless you `await` the promise. See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/215552).

Comment: Since you're using react, you're going to need to use a `useEffect` to do your data loading. You cannot do asynchronous things like fetching data in the middle of rendering. https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data

Comment: @NicholasTower Okay, so can I just wrap the entire fetchRecords function in a useEffect?

Comment: I am not a React dev (have used it but not a fan), but indeed, you're going to have to use something like `useState` or `useEffect` with refs etc... Good luck!

Comment: @ceeb with some small changes, yes. But i recommend checking out the documentation i linked, or reading a tutorial on fetching data in react.